# Code First Implementation of a Class Having Multiple Foreign Keys for a Single Table

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I currently have two classes that have the following properties. *Class1* is related to *Class2* and is linked thru 2 foreign keys.

```
public class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedById { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a few questions:

1. Should I declare the **User** class only once or should I declare one for the *OwnerId* and one for the *ModifiedById*? Something like `public virtual User Owner` and `public virtual User ModifiedBy`?
2. Is it best practice to use **public virtual** or should I use a different access modifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I declare the User class only once or should I declare one for the OwnerId and one for the ModifiedById? Something like public virtual User Owner and public virtual User ModifiedBy?

Yes you should and in that way code will be managed and easier to understand that Table1 is associated to Tabel2 in two different way for two different purpose. One indicates foreign key for Owner and another is for User who modified the record.

> Is it best practice to use public virtual or should I use a different access modifier?

This depends on your requirements that if you wanted your entities to be loaded lazily than you should define it as virtual as entity framework will override that related entities which you marked as virtual and will load lazily when you hit get on that.

Comment: Will it matter if I segregate my virtual classes from the properties to make the code cleaner? Or should it always be that the class is beneath the foreign key?

Comment: What I meant is I want to create a region for the properties and then beneath it is the region for the virtual classes. So, instead of placing `public User Owner` beneath the OwnerId, I want to place it together with `public User ModifiedBy` in one section below the class properties. I want to know if there will be any implications in doing so or not.